Writing symmetry operations as composition of group action and stabilizer
In the attached image let $K$ be the union of all colored-in edges. The symmetry group of the cube is restricted by imposing that K should be mapped onto itself. I want to find the restricted symmetry group $G\subset SO(3)$.
The solution states that each $g \in G$ can be written as a composition of an element $g_{p_i}$, which maps $p_8$ to $p_i$, and an element in $Stab_{p_8}$
From there it becomes fairly simple, since the elements in $Stab_{p_8}$ that respect K are simply $\frac{2\pi}{3}$-rotations about $\overline{p_7p_8}$ (and the identity). The only other vertex $p_8$ can be mapped on in a transformation that respects $K$ is $p_7$. The transformation is a $\pi$-rotation about the axis through the centers of $\overline{p_1p_2}$ and $\overline{p_4p_5}$ (and the identity). Taking the product of these operations gives the symmetry group of K.
So far so good, but where does this first statement come from? Why can any element in $K$'s symmetry group be written this way?
I know that for every group G acting on a set X there's an Isomorphism
$G/Stab_x \rightarrow Gx, x \in X$, but that's not exactly the same statement, is it?

